# Passing a self object in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

In the below code how to pass the div object inside validate function

```
  <div><input type="text"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="validate("Hot to pass the div objevt here")"</input> 

   <script>
    function validate()
    {
      .....
      .....
       Finally remove the div   
    }

     </script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class='elementToRemove'>
    <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="validate(this)">some text</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function validate( elem ) {
    $(elem).closest('div.elementToRemove').remove();
}
```

In the `validate()` function, `elem` will represent the `<a>` element that received the event.

Then you can wrap it in a jQuery object, and [use `.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the first `<div>` ancestor, and [use `.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove it from the DOM, and clean up any data attached, like event handlers.

Or perhaps preferable to have jQuery take care of your event handlers:

HTML:

```
<div class='elementToRemove'>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="someClassName">some text</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a.someClassName').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div.elementToRemove').remove();
});
```

Comment: If this div is enclosed in another div.Can we do $(this).closest('div').parent.remove(); And if we do parent .remove() i can use that again right

Comment: @rajeev `.closest()` gives the very close Element from the current Element http://api.jquery.com/closest , if you want to remove parent  of div, just give a reference to your parent element i.e., an ID or a class, and now use the closest on the parent element, this would be simple and time saving, rather than calling `parent()`, which begins  from parent Element (which is time consuming)

Comment: @Rajeev - @Avinash is right. I updated my answer with an example of placing a class on the `<div>` that you want to target with `.closest()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div>  blah blah <a href="#" id="remove" > Delete </a>   blah blah </div>

$(function() {
 $('a#remove').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('div').remove();
 });
});
```